# In MongoDB, can you see the commandline arguments from the shell?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to be able to connect to a MongoDB instance using mongo.exe (or any shell) and somehow **display the command-line** / config startup options. AFAIK, this does not work, but this is what I'm thinking:

```
>startupOptions()

{
   dbpath: d:\data\mongo,
   logAppend: true,
   master: false,
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,
   /* ... */
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get the args for the shell you're running, but if you're looking for the args used to start the node you're connected to, you can do the following...

```
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
```

This returns a BSONDocument which contains the arguments in both parsed and unparsed formats. You do not have to be connected to a mongos for this to work, but you do have to use the admin database.

Answer (score 2):

Kander's answer is perfect, here is just some more info for everyone:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
{
        "argv" : [
                "D:\\MongoDB\\program\\mongod.exe",
                "--config",
                "d:\\MongoDB\\config\\mongodb.config",
                "--service"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "bind_ip" : "127.0.0.1",
                "config" : "d:\\MongoDB\\config\\mongodb.config",
                "dbpath" : "D:\\data\\db",
                "directoryperdb" : "true",
                "logappend" : "true",
                "logpath" : "D:\\MongoDB\\logs\\mongodb-service.log",
                "rest" : "true",
                "service" : true
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Notice that you get both command-line arguments (`argv`) as well as the values from --config (`parsed`).